# Allow WFS searches but no total data download

Tags: geoserver, wfs, features, download

I am using GeoServer and I published some data. I want that users can extract features information by predefined queries but I do not want that they can also download the entire dataset with georeferencing. Is it possible?

Comment: What would be the result of such predefined query? Just attributes without geometry or something else?

Comment: Are the queries defined on the client by you, or available as  stored queries on the server that can be called?